# De Objecto Json para ListView

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde a todos,

tenho duas classes, a `bemVindo` e a que recebe dados em json e guarda em um objecto e após os dados json serem recebidos a class envia para a `bemVindo`os dados recebidos em String para uma TextView.
Alguma ideia de como eu possa exibir esses dados em uma ListView na `bemVindo`?

Acredito que o correto será usar ArrayLists e Adaptadores, mas não tenho muita experiencia e já tentei de diversas formas, alguém pode ajudar? Obrigado!

**Class que recebe e guarda o json em String**

```
 //DATA PARSED
        //ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);

        for(int i = 0;i<JA.length();i++){
            JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);

            String id=JO.getString("id");
            String name=JO.getString("name");      

            singleParsed = "ID: "+JO.get("id")+"\n"+
                    "Name: "+JO.get("name")+"\n";

            dataParsed=dataParsed+singleParsed+"\n";
}

/*Aqui ele seta o texto recebido para a variavel public static da bemVindo activity*/

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

    bemVindo.data.setText(this.dataParsed);
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro mude a classe que recebe e guarda o JSON em String para criar um ArrayList de String:

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);

for(int i = 0;i<JA.length();i++){
    JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);

    String id=JO.getString("id");
    String name=JO.getString("name");



    singleParsed = "ID: "+JO.get("id")+"\n"+
            "Name: "+JO.get("name")+"\n";

    items.add(singleParsed);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    bemVindo.data.setText(this.items);
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}
```

No XML da Activity crie uma ListView:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

No Java da Activity faça o seguinte:

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Fonte: https://www.androidpro.com.br/listviews/

Leia também sobre [GSON](https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-converter-objetos-java-para-ou-de-json-com-a-biblioteca-gson/28091)